# Cant use Group by - Showing Error : column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select table1.column1, table1.column2, table2.column1,  table2.column2 
from table1,table2 
where table1.column1=table2.column1 and table1.column2 in ('data1','data2','data3') and table2.column1 <> 1 
order by UPPER(column3)
```

Here, **table1.column2** is the primary key. I want to get rows which contains distinct values of **'table1.column1'** . I tried the following query,

```
select table1.column1, table1.column2, table2.column1,  table2.column2 
from table1,table2 
where table1.column1=table2.column1 and table1.column2 in ('data1','data2','data3') and table2.column1 <> 1 
group by (table1.column1)
```

It shows the following error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "table1.column2" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

based oncolumn1 distinct values, the other columns should be appropriate to that.
For example,
[image]

should result as,
[image]

Comment: On What basis, you have required The first record instead of 2nd Record? I want to know why you want to ignore the record which contains the value 673 under Column2. Is that mean, you want the top matching records only?

Comment: Does the Column2 has Foreign Key references?

Answer (score 2):

If you select 4 columns and not even one of them is a part of aggregation function  then you need to put them all in the group by clause. So this would be the code without error:

```
select table1.column1
       , table1.column2
       , table2.column1
       , table2.column2 
from table1
join table2 on table1.column1=table2.column1 
where table1.column2 in ('data1','data2','data3') 
and table2.column1 <> 1 
group by table1.column1
       , table1.column2
       , table2.column1
       , table2.column2 ;
```

Also when you do the join please do not do it like this:

```
from table1,table2 
where table1.column1=table2.column1
```

Do it like this:

```
from table1
join table2  on table1.column1 = table2.column1
```

Also a warm recommendation is to use aliases in your query's:

```
select t1.column1
       , t1.column2
       , t2.column1
       , t2.column2 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column1 
where t1.column2 in ('data1','data2','data3') 
and t2.column1 <> 1 
group by t1.column1
       , t1.column2
       , t2.column1
       , t2.column2;
```

If you want to select "I want to get rows which contains distinct values of 'table1.column1'" but you want to show other columns also, then you need to decide what do you want with other columns ? For example:

```
select t1.column1
       , max(t1.column2)
       , sum(t2.column1)
       , min(t2.column2)
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column1 
where t1.column2 in ('data1','data2','data3') 
and t2.column1 <> 1 
group by t1.column1;
```

Comment: based oncolumn1 distinct values, the other columns should be appropriate to that.

Comment: I want to eliminate the rows that contains repeated values in column1. The first row containing the value 'abc' in column1 should be taken.

Comment: @SakthivelNatarajan Please remove selecting the second table columns and try.

Comment: Whatever data he wants to ignore he shouldn't give that in where clause.

Comment: @SakthivelNatarajan. Please try with the condition you want to filter.  Your condition is based on Column1 by grouping and you are including the unwanted values from Column2 using where clause. That is why you are getting multiple values.

Comment: @VBoka. Yes. But I understand his explanation. In his question, he has the where clause. It seems like he wants to group by Column1 and ignore the values based on Column2

Comment: @VBoka. He must be the Beginner. Hope we can help him to understand how does group by works with where clause.

Comment: @VBoka. I Understand. Let's wait for his Reply. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. So I tried my best to explain my need. If you didn't get what I'm trying to say, please ignore. I'm not intended to waste your time @VBoka

Comment: If you can't understand what I'm saying, please ignore. And THANKS for your time and help.

Comment: You are not wasting my time, you just need to provide what is asked so we can help and not ignoring our questions. And I do understand what you need. You do not understand that it is not that simple as you think , when programing you need to know why is the 1231 and sdg returned. Being new means you will be happy to provide us with original data ? TWO TABLES.

Comment: I've provided the information, what I know the best in this. I'm done with this.Thank you for your help. Thanks @Mohamedasiq for your help.

Comment: @SakthivelNatarajan Have You tried with my updated answer?

Comment: @Mohamedasiq Yes, I have tried and it doesn't give the distinct values.

Comment: "I've provided the information, what I know the best in this" but @SakthivelNatarajan this is not true and please do not fool yourself with that.Invest more effort and you will be provided with better results. Also.My answer already has all you need.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be:

```
     select a.Column1,a.Column2
from Table1 a
Inner join Table2 b
on a.Column1  = b.Column1
where a.Column2 in ('1231','562','122')
group by a.column1,a.Column2
order by a.column1,a.Column2
```

Comment: Hi @Mohamedasiq how is this answer different than the one I provided ?

Comment: You are 100% Correct @VBoka. I have given complete query instead of partial explanation. For a beginner they don't know how to proceed further with simple explanation.

Comment: But @Mohamedasiq I also have full query's and partial ones and all of them were written before this answer ? as well as the additional full query's with aliases, and additional with the solution that user will maybe want. I have the same query as your answer in my answer so I am realy confused what is it that this answers is bringing to the  table

Comment: Yeah. I saw that after I have posted mine. :-). Previously You haven't given complete query. I have done Upvote for yours.

Comment: I did not posted yours. You can check the times of the posts. This is not a nice thing to say to another member of the SO. My last edit was 10 mins ago and your answer is 8 mins ago.

Comment: I didn't mean that @VBoka. Your answer is your own. I just told you before you edit I saw only a partial explanation in your answer.

Comment: No problem, I understand now. Thanks for the up vote.

Comment: Thanks @VBoka :-) Hope I didn't hurt you.

Comment: Vote up for your effort even though I do not believe it will be of any help to someone. Cheers.